# Sound coming through my speakers in ubuntu

Tags: sound

I'm just trying to get some sort of sound coming thru my speakers. They are hooked up right and a friend who installed this system tells me my soundcard is fine (whatever that is). When I try to fix the problem I'm totally lost. I'm afraid I was a little too impatient and might have downloaded some things and uninstalled a few plugins on Mozilla without really knowing what the heck I was doing. I think that is the problem but I don't know. I would say 99.9% of the troubleshooting answers I've come across read like a foreign language to me. If there is a level BELOW beginner... well, that's me. Please help if you can before I take a sledgehammer to this thing. Yes I know,must work on my patience issues.

Comment: Is just Music not playing or is there no sound at all? Try going to settings->Sound and select your sound card (or try everything) and hit the "Test Sound" Button for your speaker. If you hear something it is quite easily fixed ;)

Comment: Somehow I found that "test sound" yesterday and I didn't hear that cat meow LOL. Another thing.... I can't find the "settings->Sound on my tools,taskbar etc.Where exactly is that? Thanks Grey

Comment: Search for 'Settings' or 'System' in unity Dash (press Windows key) or press 'Alt+F2' and type 'gnome-control-center' into the popup and press enter.

Comment: I did what you suggested and this is what popped up in a box.... Failed to execute child process "gnomecontrolcenter" (No such file or directory)

Answer (score 1):

Two things to check on your speakers:

1. Is there an on/off switch hiding somewhere on one of the speakers?
2. Is there a volume control wheel hiding somewhere in the middle of the speaker cable?

Search for *Sound* in the Dash, click the Sound icon to open the **Sound** window, and check to make sure that you selected your speakers as the output.

[image]

Comment: Thank you both for taking the time to help me,I really appreciate it.The guy who installed this system is coming over to fix what damage I did  : )